# Deploy Zend Framework 2 on MAMP using GIT

Tags: git, terminal, zend-framework2, mamp

I'm trying to find information about how to deploy `Zend Framework 2` using `git` and `terminal` and set it up to work with `MAMP` Server.

I also would like to make an alias in my terminal for `zf2`. Is that possible?

Any help or link to an article that explain how to do it will help!

Comment: I think you are a bit confused about what GIT is. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDR433b0HJY) might help. Also, ZF2 is not something you "install".

Comment: Thanks. I edit my question accordingly.